# SQL: 4 Tables to 1 table with counts, groups and deductions?!

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a project with lost, found and matched luggage on airports. I made it in Java(FX) and mySQL.

This is what I have:
I have 4 tables:

1 table Airports with 2 columns:

```
Airport_id & Airport_name
```

1 table Found with 3 columns:

```
Found_id & Found_AirportID & Matched
```

1 table Lost with 3 columns:

```
Lost_id & Lost_AirportID & Matched
```

1 table Match with 3 columns:

```
Match_id & Match_LostID & Match_FoundID & Match_AirportID
```

Whenever a match is made, the Match table gets a new row with the Match_LostID (from the Lost_id) & Match_FoundID (from the Found_id) and the Match_AirportID (Found_AirportID)
The Matched (in both Found & Lost) get both set to 1, instead of NULL

All the AirportID's are linked to the Airport table.

What I want;
For each and every airport I want the count of the lost items, the count of found items and the count of matched items. BUT when a item is 'matched' it may not appear in the count of the lost and found.

So I want a table with 4 columns:
Airportname, Count of Found, Count of Lost, Count of Matched.

I've made the following Query:

```
SELECT vv.Airport_name, 
COUNT(DISTINCT gb.Found_id) countFound, 
COUNT(DISTINCT vb.Lost_id) countLost, 
COUNT(DISTINCT kt.Match_id) countMatch
FROM Airports vv
LEFT JOIN Found gb ON vv.Airport_id = gb.Found_AirportID
LEFT JOIN Lost vb ON vv.Airport_id = vb.Lost_AirportID
LEFT JOIN Match kt ON vv.Airport_id = kt.Match_AirportID
WHERE vb.Matched IS NULL OR gb.Matched IS NULL
GROUP BY vv.Airport_name
```

I manage to get all the count items for Found, Lost and Match.

e.g. New York has 2 found, 2 lost and 1 match.

This is displayed correctly in the table.
But as I said, if there is a match it should be removed from found and lost. It should be:

New York has 1 found, 1 lost and 1 match.

I tried a lot of things, 1 time I manage to do it but then a Airport is missing or it gets deducted from Found but not for lost...

I do not know what the solution is, can someone explain / give it to me?

Thanks in advance,

LTKort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `Matched IS NULL` checks in the `ON` conditions of the `LEFT JOIN`, not `WHERE`.

```
SELECT vv.Airport_name, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT gb.Found_id) countFound, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT vb.Lost_id) countLost, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT kt.Match_id) countMatch
FROM Airports vv
LEFT JOIN Found gb ON vv.Airport_id = gb.Found_AirportID AND gb.Matched IS NULL
LEFT JOIN Lost vb ON vv.Airport_id = vb.Lost_AirportID AND vb.Matched IS NULL
LEFT JOIN Match kt ON vv.Airport_id = kt.Match_AirportID
GROUP BY vv.Airport_name
```

The problem with doing it in `WHERE` is that you're only getting the results where either the `Lost` or `Found` item was matched.

Comment: Am I wrong but is this not equivalent to changing `OR` to `AND` in OP's `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @Parfait Possibly. But in general, when you're doing `LEFT JOIN` you should put conditions on the child table in the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, consider joining derived tables of aggregates to avoid many-to-many joins during the `COUNT()` evaluations:

```
SELECT a.AirportName, ftbl.countFound, lbtl.countLost, mtbl.countMatched
FROM Airports a
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT f.Found_AirportID, COUNT(f.Found_id) AS countFound 
    FROM Found f
    WHERE f.Matched IS NULL
    GROUP BY f.Found_AirportID) As ftbl
ON a.Airport_id = ftbl.Found_AirportID

LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT l.Lost_AirportID, COUNT(l.Lost_id) AS countLost 
    FROM Lost l
    WHERE l.Matched IS NULL
    GROUP BY l.Lost_AirportID) As ltbl
ON a.Airport_id = ltbl.Lost_AirportID

LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT m.Match_AirportID, COUNT(m.Match_id) AS countMatched 
    FROM Matched m
    GROUP BY m.Match_AirportID) As mtbl
ON a.Airport_id = mtbl.Match_AirportID
```